# Infinite dimensional vector space subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Let $V$ and $W$ be infinite-dimensional vector spaces over $\mathbb{C}$.

$(a)$ Is $X := \{f\in \operatorname{Hom}(V,W) :\, \operatorname{rank}(f) < \infty \}$ a subspace of $\operatorname{Hom}(V,W)$?

$(b)$ Is $Y := \{f \in \operatorname{Hom}(V,W) :\, \dim (\ker f) < \infty \}$ a subspace of $\operatorname{Hom}(V,W)$?

$(c)$ What is $X \cap Y$?

---

**Attempt:**
$(a)$ Yes, $\operatorname{rank}(A+B) \leq \operatorname{rank}(A) + \operatorname{rank}(B)$ gives closed under addition. Closure under multiplication is clear.

$(b)$ No, if $f: e_1 \mapsto 0, e_2 \mapsto e_2, e_3 \mapsto e_3,\dots$ and $g: e_1 \mapsto 0, e_2 \mapsto -e_2, e_3 \mapsto -e_3, \dots$ then $f+g$ has an infinite dimensional kernel.

$(c)$ $\dim (\ker f) + \operatorname{rank}(f) = \dim V$. Since $V$ is infinite dimensional, both $\dim (\ker f)$ and $\operatorname{rank}(f)$ cannot be finite. This means $X \cap Y$ is the empty set.

---

Is my solution correct?

Comment: For (b) you might as well just say that $0$ has an infinite-dimensional kernel, rather than bothering to write $0$ as $f+g$.

Comment: I think your solution for (c) is not right. The rank-nullity theorem requires that $V$ is of finite dimension.